# HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); not working in Android 4 EVEN WITH ASYNCTASK

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post, runtime-error

I know I should not run the network relating things on the UI thread, therefor I am using asynctask to read some things from database through php on a remote server.
However, when the code reaches --HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);-- i am getting the error -- java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 -- and thus the code does not work.

note that I am calling the asyncTask like this -- new dataRetrievalViaAsyncTask().execute(url,url,url); (the second and thrid 'url' are dummy as they do not get used) -- inside the oncreate().

What is wrong in there ?

```
class dataRetrievalViaAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url)
    {
        Log.i("tag", "inside doInBackground");
        String url2 = f_url[0];
        Log.i("tag", url2);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.i("tag",    "done : HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();");

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url2);
        Log.i("tag", "done : HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);");

        try
        {

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            Log.i("tag",    "done : httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("tag",    "done : HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);");
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.i("tag",    "done : HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();");
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.i("tag", "after : is = entity.getContent();");

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }
        // convert response to string
        return "a";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
               // enter code here

    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `LogCat` output generated from this line `Log.i("tag", url2);` give you the correct url? Can you add your `LogCat` output to your question please.

Comment: Dan, do you able to find the solution for this problem? I am also facing the same issue. Please let me know if you fixed this issue.

Comment: I NEED CLOSURE DAN :joysob:

Answer (score 1):

To save yourself further confusion do this:

```
class dataRetrievalViaAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
```

Showing your not using the futher vars.

So you would then do this:

```
 dataRetrievalViaAsyncTask().execute(url, null, null);
```

Then in your catch block change it to this:

```
 catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection", e);
    }
```

Then you'll get the proper stacktrace, hopefully being able to debug with the Class/method names and line numbers.

I assume you have the INTERNET permission in your manifest.

The only place you can have an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds is here:

```
 String url2 = f_url[0];
```

Meaning you are not sending the String URL correctly to the ASyncTask.

The other issue is you are using a `nameValuePairs` variable, but don't show us how it is instantiated. I'll gamble **this** is your issue.

Comment: Meaning you are not sending the String URL correctly to the ASyncTask. < I am sure that is sent correctly.

I am creating the nameValuePairs in the beginning of the app, when the class starts, even before onCreate().
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

and yes I have the internet permission in the manifest. Otherwise it would give an error from the first network related line rather than the httppost.

Comment: Did you change it so you log the actual error with line numbers?